# how can i save quantity to local storage

Tags: javascript, reactjs

working on a cart app - when the quantity gets bought it supposed to make the button disabled but
if I refresh it becomes active again , anyone knows how to save it to local storage?

```
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { Card } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import Rating from './Rating';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Store } from '../Store';

function Product(props){

    const {product} = props;

    const {state , dispatch:ctxDispatch} = useContext(Store);
    const {cart: {cartItems}} = state

    const addToCartHandler = async (item )=>{
      const existItem = cartItems.find((x)=> x._id === product._id);
       const quantity = existItem ? existItem.quantity+1:1 ; 

      const {data} = await axios.get(`/api/products/${item._id}`);
      if(data.countInStock < quantity){
          window.alert('sorry product is out of stock')
          return;
      }
  product.countInStock--
       ctxDispatch({
           type:'CART_ADD_ITEM' 
           , payload:{...item , quantity},
       });
      };
      

    return(

        <Card>


        <Link to={`/product/${product.slug}`}> 
          <img src={product.image} className="card-img-top" alt={product.name} />
        </Link>
        <Card.Body>
        <Link to={`/product/${product.slug}`}>
            <Card.Title>{product.name}</Card.Title>
        </Link>
        <Rating rating={product.rating} numReviews={product.numReviews} />
        <Card.Text>${product.price}</Card.Text>

        {  product.countInStock === 0 ? (

          
          <Button  color="light" disabled={true} >  Out of stock</Button>
          
        ):(
          
          <Button onClick={() => addToCartHandler(product)}>Add to cart</Button>
        )}
      </Card.Body>
    </Card>
    )}
```

product.countInStock is what needed to be saved to local storage

Comment: Here is how to use the localstorage API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem

Comment: use `window.localStorage.setItem("countInStock ", product.countInStock);`

Comment: thanks , then i should use   localStorage.getItem('countInStock') in the begining after ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should declare a variable for a disabled state like
disabled={disabledState}
so you can control the disability of the button, for setting something in localStorage just use this on onClick event handler
window.localStorage.setItem('',')

Comment: im kinda new to react and its a udemy course and the instructor messed up on this part , i did try that but the countInStock  wasn't updating at all so I'm kinda trying to fix it by myself lol

Comment: use useState for changing the state of the button state you cannot change any value from the virtual dom without using states